How to fix "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at /usr/share/nodejs/cacache/lib/util/fix-owner.js"
I am trying to install osmtogeojson globally as follows on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS;
npm install -g osmtogeojson
I receive the following error message;
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-05-24T23_49_38_390Z-debug-0.log

Here is the content of the referenced log file above:
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'osmtogeojson' ]
1 info using npm@8.5.1
2 info using node@v12.22.9
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 6ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 5ms
22 verbose logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2024-05-24T23_49_38_390Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 24ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 9ms
29 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
30 silly idealTree buildDeps
31 silly fetch manifest osmtogeojson@*
32 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
32 verbose stack     at /usr/share/nodejs/cacache/lib/util/fix-owner.js:113:7
33 verbose cwd /
34 verbose Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
35 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "osmtogeojson"
36 verbose node v12.22.9

Here is the function that includes line number 113;
106 function mkdirfix (cache, p, cb) {
107   // we have to infer the owner _before_ making the directory, even though
108   // we aren't going to use the results, since the cache itself might not
109   // exist yet.  If we mkdirp it, then our current uid/gid will be assumed
110   // to be correct if it creates the cache folder in the process.
111   return Promise.resolve(inferOwner(cache)).then(() => {
112     return mkdirp(p)
113       .then((made) => {
114         if (made) {
115           return fixOwner(cache, made).then(() => made)
116         }
117       })
118       .catch((err) => {
119         if (err.code === 'EEXIST') {
120           return fixOwner(cache, p).then(() => null)
121         }
122         throw err
123       })
124   })
125 }

I don't understand the function but it seems to be barfing on mkdir(p), right?  I am running the installation of osmtogeojson as root aswell.  Also, there is something about cache in there that I do not understand.
I tried to search for this error but I cannot find anything about it.  Any help truly appreciated.
